# How to create hotKey in Word VBA (programatically)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The title is pretty much the question

I want to make a portable hotkey, meaning if I paste the word vba code
I can still use that hotkey, something like Excel's `application.onkey`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `KeyBindings` object should do the trick. See an example here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=621

```
' \\ Code for Module1
Option Explicit 

Sub AddKeyBinding() 
    With Application 
         ' \\ Do customization in THIS document
        .CustomizationContext = ThisDocument 

         ' \\ Add keybinding to this document Shorcut: Alt+0
        .KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyAlt, wdKey0), _ 
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _ 
        Command:="TestKeybinding" 
    End With 
End Sub 

 ' \\ Code for Module2
Option Explicit 

 ' \\ Test sub for keybinding
Sub TestKeybinding() 
    MsgBox "We have a winner", vbInformation, "Succes" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! it solved my problem end code: Function must not be private `CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(Arg1:=wdKeyControl, _ Arg2:=wdKeyT), KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _ Command:="funcname"`

Comment: Hey @DaveRook, instead of editing my answer and then down-voting it, how about next time you just post your own answer? To say that the accepted answer is not useful is disingenuous.

Comment: It was -1 for a link only answer. Link only answers are bad, always have been, always will. It would have been useless if the link had died, then what? A link to nothing. So, I copied in the relevant part... Although it solved the answer at the time, if the link goes, it will not help anyone else in the future... However, I removed the downvote