# How to automatically run a subroutine in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to automatically run a sub inside the module when the template where the macro is created is loaded to the document or when the document open or new document event. My macro is a template that will be used on different computers. Is there a module code to do that?

Comment: Do you want the same macro to execute different subroutines on different computers?

Comment: Well, the sub procedure that I want to auto run is about shortcut keys like F12, It will overwrite the default function of F12, instead of save as, when you press F12, the sub that I assigned for F12 will execute. But the problem is that I still need to run that sub to make the shortcut keys work. If not then the default will be executed.

Comment: So, you want to execute your subroutine and default macro function or just execute your subroutine?

Comment: just the sub. I want it to overwrite the defualt when the template is loaded or the document open or new document.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on your workbook object

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F12}", "Module1.Testing"
End Sub
```

Where:

- {F12} is function key 12.
- Module1.Testing is your subroutine.

  EDIT after further Q/A VBA for MS Word:

Document open Event

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  Module1.Testing
End Sub
```

or

New document event

```
Private Sub Document_New()
  Modul1.Testing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm creating macro in MS-Word. And using keybinding for shortcut keys.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224480/how-to-create-hotkey-in-word-vba-programatically

Comment: My code in keybinding works fine and I put in a sub inside the module. I just want it to run automatically.

Comment: When do you want it to run? If on document open just call your subroutine on Document.Open event.